# How to implement Refer a Friend in Mobile Application?

Tags: android, ios

I like to implement Refer a Friend functionality in my mobile application (Android and iPhone).

User "A" will refer my mobile contacts via SMS (Referred user "B"). And if "B" install my referred application or the referred content, "A" will earn some reward points.

This is my scenario. Suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Google Analytics Campaign to implement this scenario.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to generate unique links for all your users, that they can then send out to their contacts.

Let's say User A shares a link with User B. When User B clicks on the link to get your app, rather than immediately redirecting to the App Store, you can make a call to your backend, with the goal being to create a digital fingerprint. Your backend can record the digital fingerprint then do a 301, 304 or 307 redirect to the App Store.

To create the digital fingerprint, your backend can then make a browser-based digital fingerprint including:
1. IP address
2. OS
3. OS version

(These can be grabbed from the request headers).

--

Later when the user opens your app, you should send up the same 3 things, IP, OS and OS version. If they match and are close time-wise, you know that they came from this click from User A's link! Then you can give User A a reward and thank him for getting User B to download the app. This is what we do at Branch Metrics, where I work. We also leverage a browser cookie that works across apps, so that we don't need to rely on fingerprinting except for the very first time we see a user in any of our apps.

You should also think about preventing fraud. You should prevent User A from referring himself, you should prevent User A from referring User B over and over, etc. This is something we work on everyday as well. Definitely spend time on fraud prevention unless you really don't care about giving out duplicate rewards to the same user. Please leave a comment if you'd like more info.